# Remove duplicates using pandas & Python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I want to remove duplicates based on my first column, Lets assume this to be 'id'. the value that I need to be removed is the records with the least complete data.

For example I have 4 records shown in the screenshot below [image]

and I want to remove duplicated based on my column id. The duplicate I would like to be removed however depends on the values in my other columns. For example lname cant be a number. It cant be NA or blank either. So for this example I want to keep the middle row and remove all other duplicates.

How do I implement a smart filter that removes duplicates by keeping the records that looks the most clean ( based on there being cleaner values in other fields).

I was looking into the panda library in python. Any direction would be appreciated.

```
data = pd.read_csv('x.csv');
data = (data.drop_duplicates(['id'], keep ='last'));
```

Comment: You're much more likely to get assistance if you post actual example data instead of screenshots. Also, what are the exact criteria, and what is your expected output?  You wrote that you want to keep the middle row, but there are 6 rows in your screenshot.  Being more specific about your constraints, and posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will speed up response time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grouped.apply`, the docs call it "flexiable apply", in which you pass a function to apply that takes a group, but in that function the group will be treated as an actual `DataFrame`.  So you filter unwanted rows and return a single `DataFrame` from that function.  Pandas will intelligently combine all the dataframes results from these calls.  See docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

example ::

```
def select(g):
    g = g.ix[g.IName.isnull(), :]
    return g

df = df.groupby('id').apply(select)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Filter your data to only keep strings/unicodes in the 'Iname' column.
data = data.loc[[isinstance(row, (str, unicode)) for row in data['Iname']], :]

# Replace empty strings with NaN values.
data.replace("", np.nan, inplace=True)

# Drop nulls, remove duplicates and keep last.
data = data[data['Iname'].notnull()].drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='last')
```